# how to add a row on top of listview

Tags: android, listview, flutter

i am very new in flutter, i have a list of rows which are part of a listview that contain   strings from lists and i want to add a seperate header on top of the listview in order to put a different content,but i keep getting errors cause the listview is combined with a futureBuilder, what sort of code should i add?

```
`body: FutureBuilder<Album>(
    future: futureAlbum,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                    child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              _sell[index]["text"],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              (snapshot.data.sellprice[index]).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color:Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              _buy[index]["text"],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              _buy[index]["symbol"],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              _currency[index]["text"],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              _currency[index]["symbol"],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              _picture[index],
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),);
              },
              itemCount: 7),

  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
body: FutureBuilder<Album>(
future: futureAlbum,
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
                child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: _content(index),
            ),);
          },
          itemCount: 7),
  }


}




_content(index){
    if(index ==  0){
      return /*Different header*/
    } else {
      return  Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  _sell[index]["text"],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Text(
                  (snapshot.data.sellprice[index]).toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color:Colors.grey),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  _buy[index]["text"],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Text(
                  _buy[index]["symbol"],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  _currency[index]["text"],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
                Text(
                  _currency[index]["symbol"],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  _picture[index],
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

lets say your header widget is of type `HeaderWidget` (could be another `Container` or a `Row` or a custom widget). Then you have to ask yourself the following question: Does the header disappear when i scroll far enough in the listview or does it always stay on top?

Scrollable:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, i) => i < 1 ? HeaderWidget() : buildChild(i-1),
  itemCount: 7,
)
```

Non-scrollable / fixed:

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    HeaderWidget(),
    ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) => buildChild(i),
      itemCount: 7,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was wrapping the ListView and the header in a column. I order to make the ListView cover the remaining height, wrap it in an Expanded widget as shown below:

```
Column(
 children: <Widget>[
   Text("Header Title")
     Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return (
            Container()
         )
       }
     )
   ),
],
```

)